# AWS Glue advice needed for scaling or performance evaluation

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Scenario:
I have a AWS Glue job which deals with S3 and performs some crawling to insert data from s3 files to postgres in rds.

Because of the file size being sometimes very large it takes up huge time to perform the operation, per say the amount of time the job runs is more then 2 days.

Script for job is written in python

I am looking for a way to be able to enhance the job in some ways such as:

- Some sort of multi-threading options within the job to perform faster execution - is this feasible? any options/alternative for this?
- Is there any hidden or unexplored option of AWS which I can try for this sort of activity?
- Any out of the box thoughts?

Any response would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need not to crawl the complete data if you just need to dump it in rds. So crawler is useful if you are going to query over that data using Athena or any other glue component but if you need to just dump the data in rds you can try following options.

1. You can use glue spark job to read all the files and using jdbc connection to your rds load the data into postgres.
2. Or you can use normal glue gob and pg8000 library to load the files into postgres. You can utilize batch load from this utility,